# Conditional object names in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, refactoring

I have a simple/stupid function that changes my state depending on what  element the user interacts with. My issue is that I have replicated pretty much the same code for each group. Is there any way I can refactor this?

```
  handleRequestDeleteChip = (data, group) => {
    // NEED REFACTORING
    if (group === "client") {
      const updatedSelectedClients = removeItem(this.state.currentJob.selectedClients, data.id);
      const updatedJobStatus = {
        ...this.state.currentJob,
        selectedClients: updatedSelectedClients
      };
      this.setState({currentJob: updatedJobStatus});
    } else if (group === "product") {
      const updatedSelectedProducts = removeItem(this.state.currentJob.selectedProducts, data.id);
      const updatedJobStatus = {
        ...this.state.currentJob,
        selectedProducts: updatedSelectedProducts
      };
      this.setState({currentJob: updatedJobStatus});
    } else if (group === "upload") {
      const updatedSelectedUplods = removeItem(this.state.currentJob.selectedUploads, data.id);
      const updatedJobStatus = {
        ...this.state.currentJob,
        selectedUploads: updatedSelectedUplods
      };
      this.setState({currentJob: updatedJobStatus});
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the "selected" item has a 1 to 1 relation with the group, you can create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (or a dictionary object) that will give you the correct item type according to the group. The rest is just using the item name:

**Note:** the map is static, so it can be moved outside of the method. This saves the need to recreate it whenever the method is invoked.

```
const itemToChange = new Map([['client', 'selectedClients'], ['product', 'selectedProducts'], ['upload', 'selectedUploads']]); // external map of options

handleRequestDeleteChip = (data, group) => {    
    const selected = itemToChange.get(group); // get the item by group

    if(!selected) { // if no selected for the group
        // handle by returning, throwing error, fallback, etc...
    }

    const updatedSelected = removeItem(this.state.currentJob[selected], data.id); // use brackets notation to get the item

    this.setState({
        ...this.state.currentJob,
        [selected]: updatedSelected // use computerd properties to set the correct type
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Great implementation!

Comment: Note that the map can be moved outside of the method. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - you can use the ability to access fields using `["field"]` rather than with `.field`.. Something like this (untested):

```
static deleteById(state, key, id) {
    const original = state[key];
    const updated = removeItem(original, id);
    state[key] = updated;
}

handleRequestDeleteChip = (data, group) => {
    const updatedJobStatus = {
        ...this.state.currentJob
    };

    if (group === "client") {
        this.deleteById(updatedJobStatus, "selectedClients", data.id);
    } else if (group === "product") {
        this.deleteById(updatedJobStatus, "selectedProducts", data.id);
    } else if (group === "upload") {
        this.deleteById(updatedJobStatus, "selectedUploads", data.id);
    }

    this.setState({currentJob: updatedJobStatus});
};
```

If you have the option of changing `group` values to match field names, then it could be even easier:

```
static deleteById(state, key, id) {
    const original = state[key];
    const updated = removeItem(original, id);
    state[key] = updated;
}

handleRequestDeleteChip = (data, group) => {
    const updatedJobStatus = {
        ...this.state.currentJob
    };

    this.deleteById(updatedJobStatus, group, data.id);

    this.setState({currentJob: updatedJobStatus});
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up using Ori Drori's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Allow it to be testable.

```
handleRequestDeleteChip = (data, group) => {
    let updatedJobStatus = { ...this.state.currentJob };
    removeCurrentJobItem(updatedJobStatus,group, data.id);
    this.setState({currentJob: updatedJobStatus});
  };

removeCurrentJobItem = (updatedJobStatus, group, id) => {
    if (group === "client") {
      const updatedItem = removeItem(updatedJobStatus.selectedClients, id);
      updatedJobStatus.selectedClients = updatedItem;
    } 

    if (group === "product") {
      const updatedItem = removeItem(updatedJobStatus.selectedProducts, id);
      updatedJobStatus.selectedProducts = updatedItem;
    } 

    if (group === "upload") {
      const updatedItem = removeItem(updatedJobStatus.selectedUploads, id);
      updatedJobStatus.selectedUploads = updatedItem;
    }
}
```

NOTE: I would also make this immutable and return a new instance from the "removecurrentJobItem" function. This allows for pure code without side effects.

You can also test this method without having to worry about state or events.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up using Ori Drori's suggestion